# Full width backgrounds responsive websites

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've run into a problem I can't quite figure out how to solve using css only.

On the responsive webpage I've got a full width background on each page, loaded onto a div with a class (bg) by the following css:

```
.bg{
   position:fixed;
   top:0px;
   z-index:-999;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background-size: cover;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
  }
```

The problem however is that these images will cause problems on mobile units if the page content is long. (The background will be stretched out to cover all page content, even the offscreen content) meaning I often only get a smudge of the upper left corner of my background visible in these units.

Since i also need this to be somewhat backwards compatible (IE 8+) I can't rely only on CSS3's 'cover' so I've run out of script-free solutions.

Any tips/ideas would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Here's a nice article on resizable backgrounds http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Comment: Try using media queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ These will be ignored in IE8, but you can use them to make the image smaller on mobile devices.

Comment: @gaynorvader: When resizing the image and using media queries I would have to compensate for the page height, which would be impossible due to the content being dynamic and thus the height changes. (It also changes depending on screen size)

Comment: Is there any special reason why you have to use an element instead of setting the background in the `body` element?

Comment: @user2269500: I know, what I'm saying is replace `height: 100%` with a fixed height at a certain screen width or height. To stop the background looking strange on mobile devices.

Comment: @gaynorvader: Thanks, I didn't quite get that ;) I'll look into ti!

Comment: Have you looked into the [Supersized! plugin](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a css element on the body tag like so

> #background{
>       background-image:url('url/to/image/of/choice.jpg');
>       background-repeat:repeat-y;
>   }

This is all in css1 so it should be backwards compatible.
you could add this to your bg or other class or id of choice.